# ¿Como puedo debugar un elemento web que solo aparece en el evento mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Tengo unos popups que dan la informacion de marcadores en un [google map](http://greenardo.cat/new/map/map.html) realizados con InfoBox. Pero me aparecen sin estilo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para crearlo ,he seguido [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404948/preventing-google-maps-move-after-displaying-infowindow) con exito, pero **el estilo** del tooltip, que no se muestra, estoy seguro que el archivo `css` esta cargado porque ademas no tengo errores el mapa se muestra correctamente a pantalla completa.

Como solo se muestra al pasar el mouse por encima, no puedo ver la clase que pertenece (aunque deberia ser `infobox-popup` y si le quito el evento `mouseout` y le aplico el estilo a mano a la clase `.infobox` (que es la que tiene cuando no se oculta automaticamente) funciona correctamente, pero vuelve al comportamiento inicial cuando vuelvo a aplicar el evento `mouseout`.

---

Asi que

- **¿Como puedo debugar un elemento web que solo aparece al pasar el mouse por encima (mouseover)?**

**EXTRA** (no necesario, pero si suena la flauta, mejor :)

- ¿Como puedo hacer que se le aplique el estilo a los tooltips creados con `infobox`?

**EMCV y FUENTES:**

- Puedes ver [**el mapa aqui**](http://greenardo.cat/new/map/map.html)
- Descargar la fuente los archivos [**en el directorio padre**](http://greenardo.cat/new/map).

Comment: Con las herramientas para desarrolladores de chrome puedes ver a tiempo real los estilos y la estructura html, incluso al hacer hover.

Comment: @Hechi he visto eso en muchas respuestas en SO pero no consigo realizarlo, puedes postear una respuesta usando el ejemplo que proporciono e incluyendo pasos y captura de pantalla para demostrarlo?

Comment: en tu caso no creo que se pueda de esa manera ya que no esta en el '`:hover` del CSS sino en un evento `mouseover` de JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el caso de Chrome (`Mac OSX` y `Windows` como mínimo), al pulsar <kbd>F8</kbd> con el *mouse* sobre el punto del mapa desencadena el evento y bloquea el `<div>`.

Después desde la pestaña clásica de `Elements` donde se ve el `html` puede ver los `css` que afectan y modificarlos o hacer las comprobaciones que quieras.

*Habría que comprobar que tecla es en otros SO y navegadores que imagino que tendrán una función similar.*

Comment: En Firefox hay también un depurador de javascript pero no sé si tiene una funcionalidad como esa, yo al menos no la conozco, se puede parar la ejecución de eventos concretos pero luego no funciona el inspector de elementos. ¿Alguna idea para los que usamos Firefox?

Comment: En `Firefox` lo he probado, se activa de igual forma (al menos en la versión de `Mac OSX`) mediante **F8**, pero el comportamiento es distinto, queda bloqueado el depurador al cambiar de pestañas pero no el evento. Puede que sea cuestión de configuración.

Comment: @blonfu sino te funciona aqui parece haber una respuesta http://stackoverflow.com/a/2099567/3850595

Comment: Gracias, estoy desde el movil pero luego lo miro,  aunque habla de firebug, yo uso las herramientas de desarrollador que vienen integradas en firefox.

Comment: @blonfu pues ya tardas en pasarte, las herramientas de firefox dejan mucho que desear....

Comment: Pues entonces voy para atrás XD. He usado firebug muchos años pero en las últimas versiones de Firefox me basta con las herramientas que trae y ya nunca instalo firebug, para emular dispositivos moviles uso Chrome porque la vista responsiva de Firefox es como redimensionar la ventana sin más.